# Stopping a postgresql instance

Tags: services, postgresql

For the sake of educational purposes I  have two identical instances of postgresql running on my machine.

I can easily stop the service of the instance that is running on port 5432 like this :

```
sudo service postgresql stop
```

What I like to know is that how I can stop the other instance (it is running on port 5433)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642892/postgresql-starting-failed

Check this if it is helpful...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`pg_ctl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html) is the postreSQL way to stop postgreSQL (in Ubuntu and Debian we should use [`pg_ctlcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pg_ctlcluster.8) which is a wrapper for `pg_ctl`). The example in that link uses option `-p 5433".

As suggested by naoko in the comments below, use `pg_lsclusters` to list clusters.

Another way is to give a `kill` signal to the process running postgresqld. To stop both at once, `killall postgresqld` might work.

Finally as suggested in the comment by psyCHOder, pgAdmin can also [stop the server](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/control-server.html), but of course that means installing that package.

Comment: I tried using `pg_ctl` it says that you have to install `postgres-xc` package.

Comment: And what is the problem  with installing postgres-xc?  How was this second instance stated?

Comment: I have started it by running `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /path/to/pgdata -c config_file=/path/to/config`

Comment: Call `pg_ctl` from `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl` too.

Comment: `pg_lsclusters` to list clusters

Answer (score 9):

Use systemctl

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu use systemctl:

```
:~/github/kafka/postgres-kafka-demo$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

:~/github/kafka/postgres-kafka-demo$ sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster 12 main stop
[sudo] password for :
```

Warning: stopping the cluster using pg_ctlcluster will mark the systemd unit as failed. Consider using systemctl:
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main

```
:~/github/kafka/postgres-kafka-demo$ sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main

:~/github/kafka/postgres-kafka-demo$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql[@version-main]
```

For example, if you are trying to stop version 10 run

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@10-main
```